# JList with ScrollPane auto-scroll bug

Tags: java

I have a JList with a ScrollPane. When i press a button, a new line is added to the JList.But the problem is that it doesn't scroll to the last element, but the second last element. Here is a portion of code used : There are no erros. Everything works good except this .

```
DefaultListModel<String> model = new DefaultListModel<String>();
JList<String> list = new JList<String>(model);
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1));
panel.add(list);
scroll = new JScrollPane(panel);
JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
p.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
p.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH); // here are more button's including the one with the action described below

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        list.setFont(new Font("Times new Roman", Font.PLAIN, 30));      
        model.add(list.getModel().getSize(), "Some text randomly"+ i++);        
        panel.repaint();panel.revalidate();     
        scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum());
}
```

Comment: I think that the actual repainting happens after this method has ended. Try calling the last line using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` like this: `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() {   scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum()); } });` (In Java 8 you can use a Lambda expression to make this statement smaller and better readable.

Comment: It gives me syntax error on tokens on this line : scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum(‌​));

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code? I did and there seems to be an invalid character somewhere in the code. Simply type in the code manually. Yep, there are some invalid invisible characters between the brackets after `getMaximum` if you copy and paste the code directly. Don't know where those came from. I just copied and pasted the code from your code sample.

Comment: Thank you ! Please post this as an answer so i can upvote you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the actual repainting happens after this method has ended. Try calling the last line using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` like this:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { 
        scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scroll.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum(‌));
    }
});
```

Beware while copy-pasting this into your IDE: There is a hidden character (zero-width non-joiner) in the HTML that is not allowed in your Java code. Just remove everything between the braces after `getMaximum()`.

(In Java 8 you can use a Lambda expression to make this statement smaller and better readable.)